# Is there any way to remove Emoji and keep other special characters in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the Emoji from a text, but trying keep some other special characters (example: á, ã, ç) from a Unicode text.

for example:

```
x<-"moises q folgado \U0001f602\U0001f602\xed�� ru hoje tá rolando goulash quarta tem linguiça acebolada e sexta tem carne assada até rimou \U0001f3a4\U0001f60ehttpstcodijgcydex6 httpstco0utmufUinscrição é só chegar se liga na programação \U0001f447\U0001f642 httpstcou7uVod6ltcancjme de saúde httpstcojwr1yt5r9l httpstcodc9doaAo4amebz4fyFmmmmmmm"
```

I already tried some codes I found on google:

```
x <- qdapRegex::rm_emoticon(x)
x <- qdapRegex::rm_non_words(teste)
x <- textclean::replace_emoticon(x)
x <- textclean::replace_emoji(x)
```

It removes not only all of the emoji but it also remove the non-English characters because of the encoding "ascii", but my non-English inputs can not be encoded into ASCII.

Sometimes a character that looks like Japanese comes up when I try to remove the emoji.

```
textclean::replace_emoticon(x)
"moisescoms q folgado \U0001f602\U0001f602攼㹤愼㸰戼㹤 ru hoje tá rolando goulash quarta tem linguiça acebolada e sexta tem carne assada até rimou \U0001f3a4\U0001f60ehttpstcodijgcydex6 httpstco0utmufUinscrição é só chegar se liga na programação \U0001f447\U0001f642 httpstcou7uVod6ltcancjme de saúde httpstcojwr1yt5r9l httpstcodc9doaAo4amebz4fyFmmmmmmm"
```

Is there any way to properly remove Emoji and keep other special characters in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emojis generally have very high Unicode values (much higher than special characters used in Western European languages) , so you could try converting to unicode numbers, removing the very high ones, then converting back.

I know this is not a perfect or production-ready solution, but it is likely to be good enough for the purposes described.

```r
remove_emojis <- function(string)
{
  intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(string)[-which(utf8ToInt(string) > 100000)])
}

remove_emojis(x)
#> [1] "moises q folgado u hoje tá rolando goulash quarta tem linguiça acebolada e sexta tem carne assada até rimou httpstcodijgcydex6 httpstco0utmufUinscrição é só chegar se liga na programação  httpstcou7uVod6ltcancjme de saúde httpstcojwr1yt5r9l httpstcodc9doaAo4amebz4fyFmmmmmmm"
```

Feliz Ano Novo...

Answer (score 1):

To *replace* with a white space rather than completely remove, here's my modified version of Allan Cameron's function:

```r
library(magrittr)
remove_emojis <- function(string) {
  string_as_int <- string %>%
    utf8ToInt()
  # replace with empty space 
  string_as_int[which(string_as_int > 100000)] <- 160
  intToUtf8(string_as_int)
}
```

To replace with any other value, you'll need to find out its decimal code point in UTF8, for a non-breaking whites space this was `160`.